# What is the name for the parts of the url specified between the forward slashes

Tags: http

```
www.example.com/part1/part2/page.html
```

www is the scheme

example is the domain

what is the correct term for part1, part 2?

And does that differ from page.html?

Comment: Some frameworks may use parts of a URL such as ASP.Net MVC found http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-2-url-routing as an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you show is not an URI, it is missing a scheme. Also, `www` is not the scheme, it is part of the host `www.example.com` (the domain of the host being `example.com`). An example of a scheme would be `http`, so your URI would become:

```
http://www.example.com/part1/part2/page.html
```

Now `/part1/part2/page.html` is the path, separated by slashes into three segments, which seems to be the term you're looking for.

[Relevant RFC: 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3).

Comment: Thanks. But what I want to know is if part1, part2 have names? Sub path? Folder? Directory?

Comment: Those are called segments.